# When should I append a directory separator at the end of a pathname?

Tags: wording, directory

Directory pathnames in code can be used mostly with or without a separator character at the end. So for example, the following commands in a Unix shell are identical:

- `ls /usr/bin`
- `ls /usr/bin/`

Or similarly in a Windows console:

- `dir C:\Windows`
- `dir C:\Windows\`

Also notably, most servers don't care about a (missing) slash after a URL path:

- http://www.google.com
- http://www.google.com/

Occasionally, I've seen this exchangeability reflected by inconsistent usage in plain text, where directory names are presented to the reader sometimes with a separator at the end and sometimes without, even in the same context.

When writing human-readable text, like a manual page or a log entry, when is it a good idea to append a directory separator after a pathname, and when not? What are advantages and disadvantages of the different representations?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with UX.

Comment: The `ls` commands are not identical if `bin` is a symbolic link.

Comment: @CL yes, the representations are different, only equivalent most of the times. That adds to unclarity for many unexperienced readers.

Answer (score 1):

If user reads `/usr/bin/` he will immediately knows that `bin` is a directory and not a file.
If user reads `/usr/bin` he has no make distinction.

How Operating Systems make this job?
When using the a command like `ls -l` in Unix or `dir` in Windows, the output makes the distinction between files and directories like this

- Unix

  `-rw-r--r--   1 root root   15276 Oct  5  2004 a2ps.cfg`

  `drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2007 acpi`

where the first symbol is `-` for a file and `d` for a directory

- Windows

  `05/14/2010  02:00 AM               135 README.TXT`

  `04/26/2013  11:08 AM    <DIR>          users`

where `135` is the file size in bytes (meaning it's a file), and `<DIR>` is the the directory tag.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers generally append a trailing slash when visiting the root of a website (www.google.com).

In terms of web design/development, there is a big difference between the following URLs if you're using relative links:

- example.com/foo
- example.com/foo/

If there is a link to `./` within the document (eg. `<a href="./">elsewhere</a>`), the page that you'll end up on is quite different:

- example.com/foo -> example.com/
- example.com/foo/ -> example.com/foo/